# Will Positron Cause flow of electricity?

Tags: electricity, electrons, antimatter

Recently someone told me about antimatter. Antimatter is something that is completely opposite to matter. What I would like to know is let's say this universe was made of Anti-Matter.

So since the concept of electricity means that when the negative charges moves from one place to another(in a way) then the electricity is generated. However if these electrons were replaced by the positive Positron would it be possible to generate what we now call as electricity.

P.S. If yes, would the Protons could also generate electricity if they are made to flow.

Comment: [Here's a related question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141841/is-a-flow-of-ionized-water-an-electric-current/141846#141846). Of course, it doesn't concern antimatter, but the same idea applies there as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are being imprecise about electricity.  It's probably better to just think of electricity as current.  You have a current whenever you have a charge moving.

To your question, yes, positrons are just as good as electrons for carrying a charge.  There is no difference between "positron electricity" and "electron electricity".

Another way to see this is to imagine a wire carrying electrons in a current.  If you look at the wire as non-moving then the moving electrons will appear to be the source of the current.  If instead you're flying alongside the electrons and looking at them as non-moving then you will see the protons in the wire as moving (in the opposite direction) and you will see the protons as the source of the current.

**That is, electrons moving left to right is the same current as a positive charge like protons or positrons moving right to left.**

For what it's worth, in ion solutions you can have have electrical currents carried by positively or negatively (or both!) charged ions because in a fluid the ions are free to move.

Comment: So is this why you can use either an acidic or a basic solution as an electrolyte for electrolysis?

Comment: Yeah but it's not restricted to acids and bases.  For example table salt (NaCl) will form Na+ and Cl- ions in solution and that allows for conductivity too.

Answer (score 1):

Current is basically the flow of charges.Well what i think so whatever charge it is it will flow and will cause the production of current and if there is a production of current electricity is automatically formed.For example the current positron generator.Here is a link where there is a PDF which is all about Dirac current generator
http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEQQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dpedtech.com%2Fdirac.pdf&ei=brNlVK7sM5C1uQThqILoCw&usg=AFQjCNGQBdZBsYFjOrKrmWnwEYmZGBqEsw&sig2=pAkRyDC3C3YdjdlAGvRumw