# Would a flow of current (of positrons) zap us?

Tags: electricity, electrons, electric-current, antimatter

I have read this question:

[Will Positron Cause flow of electricity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146699/will-positron-cause-flow-of-electricity)

> > To your question, yes, positrons are just as good as electrons for carrying a charge. There is no difference between "positron electricity" and "electron electricity".That is, electrons moving left to right is the same current as a positive charge like protons or positrons moving right to left.

Now electric shock is caused by an electric current flowing through our body.

> > Electrical injury is a physiological reaction caused by electric current passing through the body.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury

Now this is where it gets confusing because the electric current is defined with electrons usually or ions.

> > An electric current is the rate of flow of electric charge past a point[1]:2[2]:622 or region.[2]:614 An electric current is said to exist when there is a net flow of electric charge through a region.[3]:832 In electric circuits this charge is often carried by electrons moving through a wire. It can also be carried by ions in an electrolyte, or by both ions and electrons such as in an ionized gas (plasma).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current

Now specifically, it says that it is often carried by electrons moving through a wire or ions in an electrolyte, or both. But it is not talking about positrons.

Our body is full of electrons, and the flow of positrons could annihilate the electrons in our body. Without the electrons, our body would become ionized (the atoms would lose the negative charge), but would that lead to an electrical shock or zap?

Question:

1. would a flow of current (made of positrons) zap us?

Comment: You would get a double whammy due to their charge and due to the fact that they are the antiparticles of electrons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would, but such a positron shock would only be possible if you had a wire made of antimatter, and then you would have to somehow isolate the antimatter wire from the matter world which surrounds it, otherwise there would be a huge explosion. There are so many problems to overcome with this scenario that it can never be more than a thought experiment, it is quite impossible in the real world. In the thought experiment, the positrons which entered your body would annihilate with the electrons they encountered, so you would probably explode. Perhaps it would be easier to inject the positrons by means of a particle beam, but that would also present problems, though less difficult ones. But you are never going to find a volunteer for such experiments, so they will always have to remain just thought experiments.

Comment: Is there any chance the experiment might turn me blue and give me super powers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Manhattan) ?

Comment: No chance at all, especially as it can never be more than a thought experiment.